# Restrict unison to work only on certain folder (on the remote server)

Tags: permissions, synchronization, unison

Considering the scenario where *Server1* wants to keep folder `/x` synchronized between itself and *Server2*. So apparently one have to add a new (SSH) user to Server2 allowing for this.

So we result in a command similar to:

```
$ unison -batch /x ssh://username@1.1.1.1//x
```

What is the most straightforward way to allow this user only access to the folder `/x`? What if I need to synchronize many different folders of *Server2* across different servers? Do I need a user per "folder"?

With `rsyncd` I could have created a configuration file defining the AAA for the folder, e.g.:

```
path = /x
auth users = userA, userB, userC
secrets file = ...
```

Is there a similar way with Unison?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#perms):

> All files are created with the owner and group of the server process.

So specifying authorized users cannot be done directly with Unison itself, but instead you do it while specifying the permission associated the files you are syncing, the user created on Server2, and the Unison process itself.